# Percona Multi Master Cluster

Tags: mysql, percona

```
update remote_request set completed_time = "2014-08-20 20:31:07" where id = "P1257-K420C-7N4M5-VM125-4E57R-FE420"
```

This query for whichever reason, is taking about 3 seconds while several instances of this application are processing (about 150).. there all checking in with that table about once per second using exactly that query.

Any particular reason this is so slow? The setup is 4 servers, to which I am currently only inserting heavily into one.  The other three are essentially slaves and for display only/backup/experimentation.

Indexes for the table are in place.. and when I am not running this many instances of the same task there is no issue.  Prior to installing the cluster the same crons did not report this kind of latency.

All servers are connecting via gigabit lan.   What kind of settings would you also want to know from me, and what kind of settings can I use to help fix these problems?

My my.cnf is:

```
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_files_in_group=1
innodb_log_file_size=256M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=20GB
innodb_lru_scan_depth=4000
innodb_flush_neighbors=0
innodb_log_buffer_size=256M
transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED
innodb_io_capacity = 25000
innodb_io_capacity_max = 50000
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=4
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_checksum_algorithm = crc32
innodb_file_per_table = true
innodb_doublewrite=0
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_purge_threads=4
table_open_cache=15000
open_files_limit=15000
max_connections=15000
innodb_read_io_threads = 32
innodb_write_io_threads = 32
innodb_change_buffering=all
loose-innodb_sync_array_size=16
sync_binlog=0
query_cache_type=OFF
thread_cache_size=1000
back_log=2000
connect_timeout=15
loose-metadata_locks_hash_instances=256
max_prepared_stmt_count=1048560
loose-performance_schema=0

# --- below is Percona Server Specific ---
innodb_sched_priority_cleaner=39
innodb_log_block_size=2048
innodb_adaptive_hash_index_partitions=65
skip-name-resolve

wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://db1,db2,db3,web1
wsrep_node_address=db3
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
wsrep_cluster_name=data
wsrep_sst_auth="<<filled out correctly>"
binlog_format=ROW
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup-v2

log_slow_admin_statements=1
log_slow_rate_limit=1
sort_buffer_size = 512K
concurrent_insert = 2
```

Let me know what else you think I might need.   I might mention that some nodes in the cluster are not the same strength as the primary db server.  Technically the web1 database is the strongest but most of the work is done on 3.. which i have shown the config for you for.. and all of them are running a very similar config.  As you can tell i dont care at all for ACID compliance.

Comment: You do know that when you're using Galera, each write waits for all of the nodes, right?  That's how consistency is maintained. Reads are independent, with the work done by just the node where you're connected, but on writes, a cluster is only as fast as the weakest link and only as responsive as the slowest or most distant node.  (Just checking.)

Comment: I do know that yes. These nodes are all gigabit lan connected and none of them are terribly high processor load.  This query should resolve nearly instantly on all of them.  I would think anyway, is there a way to debug that to know that your waiting for a specific node?